# Getting "Error waiting for Virtual Network Rule "" (server, rg) to be created or updated..." for azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule

Tags: azure, mariadb, terraform, vnet

I'm building a Terraform config for my infrastructure deployment, and trying to connect an  azurerm_mariadb_server resource to an azurerm_subnet, using an azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule, as per [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/mariadb_virtual_network_rule.html).

The vnet, subnet, mariadb-server etc are all created, but I get the following when trying to create the vnet_rule.

```
Error: Error waiting for MariaDb Virtual Network Rule "vnet-rule" (MariaDb Server: "server", Resource Group: "rg") 
to be created or updated: couldn't find resource (21 retries)

  on main.tf line 86, in resource "azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule" "vnet_rule":
  86: resource "azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule" "mariadb_vnet_rule" {
```

I can't determine which resource can't be found - all resources except the azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule are created, according to both the bash shell output and Azure portal.

My config is below - details of some resources are omitted for brevity.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 2.27.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "${var.resource_group_name}-rg"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name = "${var.prefix}Vnet"
  address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name = "${var.prefix}backendSubnet"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
}

resource "azurerm_mariadb_server" "server" {
  # DB server name can contain lower-case letters, numbers and dashes, NOTHING ELSE
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name = "${var.prefix}-mariadb-server"
  location = var.location
  sku_name = "B_Gen5_2"
  version = "10.3"
  ssl_enforcement_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_mariadb_database" "mariadb_database" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name = "${var.prefix}_mariadb_database"
  server_name = azurerm_mariadb_server.server.name
  charset = "utf8"
  collation = "utf8_general_ci"
}

##  Network Service Endpoint (add DB to subnet)  

resource "azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule" "vnet_rule" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name = "${var.prefix}-mariadb-vnet-rule"
  server_name = azurerm_mariadb_server.server.name
  subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.backend.id
}
```

The issue looks to arise within ['func resourceArmMariaDbVirtualNetworkRuleCreateUpdate'](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/4048/files), but I don't know Go, so can't follow exactly what's causing it.
If anyone can see an issue, or knows how to get around this, please let me know!

Also, I'm not able to do it via the portal - step 3 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-manage-vnet-portal) shows a section for configuring VNET rules, which is not present on my page for 'Azure database for mariaDB server'. I have the Global administrator role, so I don't think it's permissions-related.

Comment: Is Allow access to Azure services turned on? It looks like that might need to be turned off for the settings to be available.

Comment: Thanks TH - the MS documentation indicates "Allow access to Azure Services" should be disallowed generally, although it's admittedly implicit wrt use with azurerm_mariadb_virtual_network_rule. I've tried enabling it and applying the terraform again, but it made no difference, to either the terraform script outcome or the presence of the VNET config on the portal.

Comment: Ah so it was previously already off. I would still ignore Terraform for the time being and figure out how to enable the config section in the portal, as it sounds like there's a problem on the Azure end that Terraform is just a victim of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [creating and manage Azure Database for MariaDB VNet service endpoints and VNet rules by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-manage-vnet-portal)

The key point is that

> Support for VNet service endpoints is **only for General Purpose and
> Memory Optimized servers**.

So change the code  `sku_name = "B_Gen5_2"` to `sku_name = "GP_Gen5_2"` or other eligible `sku_name`.

> sku_name - (Required) Specifies the SKU Name for this MariaDB Server.
> The name of the SKU, follows the tier + family + cores pattern (e.g.
> B_Gen4_1, GP_Gen5_8). For more information see the [product
> documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mariadb/servers/create#sku).

It takes a few minutes to deploy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nancy - I had used the code with sku version in the [Example Usage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/mariadb_server.html) on the documentation, without realising it was from the 'basic' category.
I created a config from the portal and when comparing the two "Azure Database for MariaDB server" pages (portal vs terraform) the difference popped out. I knew it was only available on non-basic tiers, but had overlooked that, and the error message was frustratingly vague.